# In Servlet, I get NULL value on submit button form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where which has 2 submit buttons (Delete, Submit). If the user clicks on Delete button, I show a popover windows to confirm the action.

Look at [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m26rca8u/)

HTML Form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <div class="form-row mb-3">
      <button type="submit" name="bt" value="delete" class="btn btn-dark mr-3">Delete</button>
      <button type="submit" name="bt" value="update" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="alertDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header no-borderb">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Confirm Delete</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer no-bordert">
                    <button id="cfmContinue" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">DELETE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('form').on("click", ":submit", function (e) {                    
  var submitValue = $(this).val();
  if (submitValue === 'delete') {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#alertDelete').modal('show');
  }
});

$('#cfmContinue').click("click", function (e) {
  console.log("cfmContinue clicked");
  $('#myForm')[0].submit();
});
```

However, in my servlet when I read the submit button I get null value

```
String submit = request.getParameter("bt");
System.out.println("submit = " + submit);
```

> submit = null

I don't understand why I am getting NULL value.. I get normally all the other inputs of the form..

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround... I read the value of the submit button of the panel and I insert this value to a hidden input of my form and it worked..

```
<input name="btAction" type="text" class="form-control hidden">      

$('#cfmContinue').click("click", function (e) {
   var cfmContinue = $('#cfmContinue').val();
   $("input[name=btAction]").val(cfmContinue);
   $('#myForm')[0].submit();
});
```

**However**, I would like a lot to know why I my first approach isn't working... I think the problem is in the form and not in the server side...

Comment: I think it may be because your submit buttons don't have `name` attributes?

Comment: My 2 submit buttons have `name` attributes. I added also in the delete button inside the panel but still `NULL`...